# Advise needed to make a good nested else/if statement in function

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm currently building a function that has to do with a pharmacist's input and I was wondering if this was the proper way to construct it using else/if statements. Am I lacking in some parts? (I've been getting this one single "expected declaration of the '}'" error that's been driving me crazy and have been trying to fix it for the past hour or so but to no avail.)

I would love to hear your advice on the parts that I might be missing out.

I've also listed the location of the error in the code below.

Thank you so much!

```
void pharm_page()
{
    int choice3;
    char pharm_user[30];
    char pharm_pass[30];
    char ship, ship_choice;
    bool value_found = true;
    
    system ("pause");

    cout << "\n --------Pharmacist Login-------";
    cout << "\n\n Please enter your username: ";
    cin >> pharm_user;
    cout << "\n Please enter your password:";
    cin >> pharm_pass;

    if ((strcmp (pharm_user, USER1) == 0) &&
    (strcmp (pharm_pass, USER1PASSWORD) == 0))
    {
        getchar();
        system("pause");
        
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Success! You will be redirected to the pharmacist page." << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        
        cout << "------------------ Pharmacist Page -----------------\n" << endl
        << "Press 1: Access Patient Records" << endl;
        cin >> choice3;
        
        if (choice3 == 1)
        {
           const int ship_WM = 8.00;
           const int ship_EM = 12.00;
           int patient_id; 
           bool value_found = true;
           cout << "-------------- Enter patient ID : ";
           cin >> patient_id;
           cin.ignore();

            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_P; i++)
               {
                        if (patient_id == pat[i].p_id)
                    {
                        cout << "Patient Name : " << pat[i].p_name << endl
                        << "Patient ID : " << pat[i].p_id << endl
                        << "Doctor Name : " << pat[i].p_doctor << endl
                        << "Appointment Date : " << pat[i].p_date << endl
                        << "Medicine Expiry Date : " << pat[i].expiry << endl
                        << "Medicine Name : " << pat[i].med_name << endl
                        << "Medicine Quantity : " << pat[i].med_q << endl
                        << "Direction of Use : " << pat[i].direct << endl
                        << "Patient's Address: " << pat[i].p_add << endl
                        << "Continue prescription? " << pat[i].option << endl
                        << "\n" << endl;
                        
                        cout << "\t\t========================================================================================\n\n";
                        cout << "\t\tPlease take note that fridge items e.g. insulin, medication in liquid form e.g. syrup or \n";
                        cout << "\t\tlotion and pressurized canisters e.g. inhalers are not eligible for postage. Kindly      \n";
                        cout << "\t\t\t\t\tsource at the nearest hospital/pharmacy.\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n";
                        cout << "\t\t========================================================================================\n\n";
                        
                        cout << "--------- State the method of pick-up for patient's medicine (Press A for 'Shipping' or B for 'Pick-up'): ";
                        cin >> ship;
                        
                        if (toupper(ship) == 'A')
                        {
                            cout << "You have chosen to ship the medicine. Please enter the shipping zone of the patient to determine shipping charges. (EG: Press C for 'WM' or D for 'EM'): " << endl;
                            cin >> ship_choice;
                            
                                if (toupper(ship_choice) == 'C')
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        ofstream file_label("patient.txt");
                                        if(file_label.is_open())
                                        {
                                        file_label << "Patient Name : " << pat[i].p_name << endl;
                                        file_label << "Patient ID : " << pat[i].p_id << endl;
                                        file_label << "Doctor Name : " << pat[i].p_doctor << endl;
                                        file_label << "Appointment Date : " << pat[i].p_date << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Expiry Date : " << pat[i].expiry << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Name : " << pat[i].med_name << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Quantity : " << pat[i].med_q << endl;
                                        file_label << "Direction of Use : " << pat[i].direct << endl;
                                        file_label << "The medicine will be shipped to the patient's address at " << pat[i].p_add << "." << endl;
                                        file_label << "Shipping charges: RM" << ship_WM << endl;
                                        file_label.close();
                                        
                                        cout << "\n" << endl;
                                        break;
                                        }  
                                    }
                                }
                                    else if (toupper(ship_choice) == 'D')
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                        {
                                        ofstream file_label("patient.txt");
                                        if(file_label.is_open())
                                        {
                                        file_label << "Patient Name : " << pat[i].p_name << endl;
                                        file_label << "Patient ID : " << pat[i].p_id << endl;
                                        file_label << "Doctor Name : " << pat[i].p_doctor << endl;
                                        file_label << "Appointment Date : " << pat[i].p_date << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Expiry Date : " << pat[i].expiry << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Name : " << pat[i].med_name << endl;
                                        file_label << "Medicine Quantity : " << pat[i].med_q << endl;
                                        file_label << "Direction of Use : " << pat[i].direct << endl;
                                        file_label << "The medicine will be shipped to the patient's address at " << pat[i].p_add << "." << endl;
                                        file_label << "Shipping charges: " << ship_EM << endl;
                                        file_label.close();
                                        
                                        cout << "\n" << endl;
                                        break;
                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                        cout << "Unable to open file. Please try again once the program restarts.";
                                    }
                                }
                            else if (toupper(ship) == 'B')
                            {
                                           for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                                           {
                                           ofstream file_label("patient.txt");
                                           if(file_label.is_open())
                                           {
                                           file_label << "Patient Name : " << pat[i].p_name << endl;
                                           file_label << "Patient ID : " << pat[i].p_id << endl;
                                           file_label << "Doctor Name : " << pat[i].p_doctor << endl;
                                           file_label << "Appointment Date : " << pat[i].p_date << endl;
                                           file_label << "Medicine Expiry Date : " << pat[i].expiry << endl;
                                           file_label << "Medicine Name : " << pat[i].med_name << endl;
                                           file_label << "Medicine Quantity : " << pat[i].med_q << endl;
                                           file_label << "Direction of Use : " << pat[i].direct << endl;
                                           file_label << "The medicine will be shipped to the patient's address at " << pat[i].p_add << "." << endl;
                                           file_label << "Shipping charges: None "  << endl;
                                           file_label.close();
                                        
                                           cout << "\n" << endl;
                                           break;
                                            }
                                            }
                            }
                        }  
                    }
            else
                value_found = false;
    }
        if(value_found)
        cout << "No record of patient in database. Please re-enter current patient's number and try again. ";
    else
        cout << "Wrong input. Please try again." << endl;
            }
    } <============================================================== (that one error is located here)
else
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Your credentials are wrong. Please enter the right credentials once the program has been terminated." << endl;
            }  
        }
}
```

Comment: That's normally a not a place for asking about 'nice' code. But since you are doing something... Start from avoiding long nesting blocks. `if ((strcmp (pharm_user, USER1) == 0) && (strcmp (pharm_pass, USER1PASSWORD) == 0)) { /* all your code here */}`, might be easier as `if ((strcmp (pharm_user, USER1) != 0) || (strcmp (pharm_pass, USER1PASSWORD) != 0)) { cout << "error...";  return; }` and after that all your other code w/o nesting.

Comment: all that you have in `if (toupper(ship) == 'A')`, `else if (toupper(ship) == 'B')`, etc could be made a separate functions.

Comment: `ofstream file_label("patient.txt"); if(file_label.is_open())`, just open file once at the beginning and close once in the end.

Comment: Your code is badly indeted. You can use your IDEs formatting function or some online formatter like http://format.krzaq.cc to indent it properly. Then it's easier to spot missing or superflous braces. Also, in my opinion, it's a good habit to _always_ use braces after control statements, even if the following code is only a single line. Helps to avoid such errors.

Comment: You are missing a lot of curly brackets. The closing one for your ```void pharm_page()```is on line 156. The remaining 8 lines are all outside of that function

Comment: All in all, if you take to your hart all the bits of advice included in the comments, you'll save yourself from another hours of hunting for trivial errors.

Comment: thank you all for the replies! didn't expect so many good feedback over my terrible lines of code. i'll get to work right this instance:)

Answer (score 0):

1. A good base line is that if you have a function that is long enough for you not to see it in one page, you should generate sub-functions.
2. Another good base line is that if you can easily name a sub-segment of your code, you should consider making it another function.
3. If you see that you repeat nearly similar code several times, like your writing lines, it's time to refactor. Avoid repeating the same code all over.
4. Most important: C++ is an OOP language. Use it as one.

For example, take your lines

```
               cout << "Patient Name : " << pat[i].p_name << endl
                    << "Patient ID : " << pat[i].p_id << endl
                    << "Doctor Name : " << pat[i].p_doctor << endl
                    << "Appointment Date : " << pat[i].p_date << endl
                    << "Medicine Expiry Date : " << pat[i].expiry << endl
                    << "Medicine Name : " << pat[i].med_name << endl
                    << "Medicine Quantity : " << pat[i].med_q << endl
                    << "Direction of Use : " << pat[i].direct << endl
                    << "Patient's Address: " << pat[i].p_add << endl
                    << "Continue prescription? " << pat[i].option << endl
                    << "\n" << endl;
```

I'm not sure what `pat` stores, but given that it has members, it's at least a structure. Now why does that structure or class not have a method like `print()` or `to_string()`? Which would reduce your lines above to

```
cout << path[i].to_string() << endl;
```

Do similar things in other parts where you print a lot of things and your code should be far better to read already. Note that a `to_string()` method suits well as that would also work with your `ofstream`.

Question, is that what you show us a function or a method? It should be the latter. You should have something like a class `PharmacyInterface` which has such functionality as methods. Basically every single access you can name should be a method. Something like accessing the data of a single patient should be a method. Entering the password (and storing a boolean that it was successfully entered) should be a method. All those methods should read very shortly and straight-forwarded.
Basically, for anything that you nest, ask yourself if you can easily name it. If so, make it it's own method.

As for your error, use a proper IDE. If you use auto-indentation, the line with the missing { or } will stick out, and maybe even be marked as bad. Also, you can check to which opening brace a closing brace belongs by clicking behind it, a good IDE will then indicate the opening brace.
But in general, if you have troubles finding an incorrect bracing, your code is simply too convoluted, and you should use what I wrote above.

Lastly, I strongly recommend that you put your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another StackExchange website which concerns itself with coding style rather than fixing bugs like StackOverflow does.
Note that the code you post there will be ripped apart, and that is quite useful for you to learn things.

Edit: Another thing I noticed is that you have a for loop that searches for an ID. This creates an avoidable nesting. Instead, have another method (or function if you want to go procedural) called `size_t patient_index_from_id(int id)` or similar, which does the search. Saves you from one nesting and can be reused.

Comment: I think the advice that 'if it _can_ be a member function ["method"], it _should_ be' might prove to be controversial, since many would argue oppositely that one should prefer free functions and only use member functions where they need `private` access. But it may be too opinionated either way. Things that can be discrete functions definitely should, to keep code in small and self-contained, easy to reason about blocks - but I don't know that those should necessarily be _member_ functions.

Comment: @underscore_d Yeah, I mean, stuff like that pretty much *has* to be opinionated, as we talk about coding style after all. Thing is, I think that OP would improve by adopting my ways. Other styles would also work, but we need to start *somewhere*. At some point, OP will use their own style anyway. That said, in this case, I'd pretty much say that this should be done OOP style. A system like that has data to store. Note how `pat` is not defined within that code? If it is a function and not a method, then `pat` would be a global variable, which I think we agree that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @underscore_d Oh and yeah, your first sentence, agreed. Wasn't my intend to express that there should not be any functions at all. I myself use functions all the time. Didn't wanted to express that all functions should be replaced by methods or anything. Which sentence of my answer does express that? Will rewrite it to be clearer.

Comment: hey @Aziuth! as a beginner to this (and this small code being a larger part of another code fora school project), i really like your approach to this! i was advised to not practice using class and sub-functions in an existing function but with the recommendation of the folks over here, i might as well give it a try, right?

Comment: @ottersgalore Depends, I think you should ask your teacher again. "Advised" might easily mean "supposed". But other than that, a very basic concept in programming is divide-and-conquer. If you got several small functions, those are easier to debug than a big one. In any case, make sure not to go too far over your head. Classes are very useful, but if you feel unsure, do it step by step. But I thought you used something like a class or structure already? After all, the patients in your program have members.

Comment: @aziuth structures, yes! just not class yet because my lecturer told us that this isn't going to be an object-oriented specific program. i've seen tons of folks recommend class though, unfortunately i'm restricted in that area :(

also, i've debugged the program thanks to you and the folks here! phase 2 approaches where i now have to try and include a receipt function hahaha